# Using JQuery to load an html page into a container on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to using the load function to import html from one page into another on click, but nothing seems to be happening when I click the button. How can I fix the problem?

The console error I am receiving is:

> jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Ian/Google%20Drive/Project%20Georgia/history.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Here is the script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn-history").click(function(){
            $("#displayed-text").load("history.html");
       });
    });
</script>
```

The input button:

```
<input id="btn-history" type="image" src="img/history.gif" alt="Golden Lion" class="menu-icon">
```

And the container:

```
<p id="displayed-text">This is where text will show up.</p>
```

**Edit:**

After learning I cannot load from the C drive, I uploaded the page to Google Drive and modified my script as follows:

```
        $("#btn-history").click(function(){
            $("#displayed-text").load("https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fJXEIdt8OCT2ozTlNaRktOZm8/view?usp=sharing");
       });
```

However, am still receiving errors.

> jquery.min.js:4 Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
>
> send @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> r._evalUrl @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> Ja @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> append @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> T @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> html @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> i @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> A @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> jquery.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>
> file:///C:/static/file/client/js/1539922584-projector_viewer__ka.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
>
> send @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> r._evalUrl @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> Ja @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> append @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> T @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> html @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> i @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> A @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> VM644:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _initProjector is not defined
>
> at :1:1
>
> at p (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> at Ja (jquery.min.js:3)
>
> at r.fn.init.append (jquery.min.js:3)
>
> at r.fn.init. (jquery.min.js:3)
>
> at T (jquery.min.js:3)
>
> at r.fn.init.html (jquery.min.js:3)
>
> at Object. (jquery.min.js:4)
>
> at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>
> (anonymous) @ VM644:1
>
> p @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> Ja @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> append @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> T @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> html @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> i @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> A @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> jquery.min.js:3 GET file:///C:/static/file/client/css/469530624-projector_css_ltr.css net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> Ja @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> append @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> T @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> html @ jquery.min.js:3
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> i @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
>
> A @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:4
>
> cb=gapi.loaded_0:48 Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target 
>   origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
>
> (anonymous) @ cb=gapi.loaded_0:48

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. One quick question, is your history.html in the same directory as your script/page you are trying to load it into?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local

read here. maybe it will help

Comment: So I can't load something from my C drive?

Comment: @IanBurns You can by disabling it from jquery but you shouldn't!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `e.preventDefault()`:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-history").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#displayed-text").load("history.html");
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I put this answer up _before_ edits were made to the original question (cross origin errors etc). Follow the link provided by @Mihai T